# Multidimensional Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have

```
var items = new Array('0,364,2113,0','0,0,0,0');
```

and I want to convert it to multidimensional array
 like

```
var Finalitems = [[0, 364,2113,0], [0, 0, 0,0]];
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, and you did not mention what you have tried already.

Comment: -1 Voted because the requested solution is different to the one accepted as correct. Poor specification of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
var items = new Array('0,364,2113,0','0,0,0,0');
var finalitems = [];

for (var i in items)
{
    vals = items[i].split(',');
    finalitems.push(vals);
}
```

?

Comment: That's what I was gonna say, except you give back an array of strings.

Comment: Please do not tell people to use `for-in` on an Array in JavaScript. It's just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop the items array, and split on `,`. That will return a new array, which you can add to a new `double dim array`.

Something like this:

```
declare double dim array "dimarray";
declare int i = 0;
foreach(...in "items")
{
  var "newarray" = split(...);
  dimarray[i] = newarray;
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To give what you've asked for, an Array of Numbers *(not Strings)*, do this.

```
var finalArray = items.map(function(item) {
                              return item.split(",").map(Number);
                           });
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>


function onBtnPress()
{
    var items = new Array('0,364,2113,0','0,0,0,0');
    var nItems, i;
    var result = new Array();

    nItems = items.length;
    for (i=0; i<nItems; i++)
    {
        curStr = items[i];
        curItemArray = curStr.split(',');
        len = curItemArray.length;
        for (index=0; index<len; index++)
        {
            curItemArray[index] = parseInt(curItemArray[index]);
        }

        result.push(curItemArray);
    }
    console.log(result);
}
</script>



<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='button' onclick='onBtnPress();' value='click me' >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't see what's wrong with this, it appears to work. It's a little on the long side but, at worst, that would make it _less_ useful rather than _not_ useful.